# программа по преобразованию строки

Tags: python, python-3.x

> s = 'aaaabbсaa' преобразуется в 'a4b2с1a2', то есть группы одинаковых символов исходной строки заменяются на этот символ и количество его повторений в этой позиции строки.
>
> Напишите программу, которая считывает строку, кодирует её предложенным алгоритмом и выводит закодированную последовательность на стандартный вывод. Кодирование должно учитывать регистр символов

Вот что я сделал, но не работает и не могу понять почему:

```
str1 = input()
str2 = ""
index = 0
tmp = len(str2)
for i in range(len(str1)):
    tmp = len(str2)
    if i ==0 and len(str1) == 1:
        index +=1
        print(str1[i] + str(index))
        break
    elif i ==0:
        str2 = str2 + str1[i]
        index +=1
    elif i >0 :
            if tmp ==0 :
                str2 = str2 + str1[i]
                index == 1
                #tmp ==1
            elif str2[tmp-1] == str1[i] and tmp ==1:
                index +=1
            elif tmp >1   :
                index +=1
                print(str2[tmp-1])
            elif str2[tmp] == str1[i] and str2[tmp -1] == str1[i]:
                index +=1
            else: str2=str2 + str1[i] + str(index); index==0; tmp=len(str2)
print(str2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby

s = input()
print(''.join('{}{}'.format(k, sum(1 for _ in g)) for k, g in groupby(s)))
```

Comment: `sum(1 for _ in g)` можно заменить на `len(list(g))`

Answer (score -1):

```
# рабочий код

s = input()
l = len(s)
cnt = 1
for i in range(l):
    if i == (l - 1):
        print(s[i] + str(cnt), end='')
    else:
        if s[i] == s[i + 1]:
            cnt = cnt + 1
        else:
            print(s[i] + str(cnt), end='')
            cnt = 1
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -2):

Без импорта

```
s = 'aaaabbсaa'
r = ''
for c in s:
    if not len(r):
        r = c + '1'
    else:
        if c == r[-2]:
            r = '{}{}'.format(r[:-1], int(r[-1]) + 1)
        else:
            r = '{}{}{}'.format(r, c, '1')

print(r)
a4b2с1a2
```