# Цикл не прерывается по неясным причинам

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал небольшой код, который принимает строку 'aaaabbcaa', и возвращает 'a4b2c1a2', но по каким-то причинам цикл не прекращается, что наводит на мысль, что оператор break не вызывается. Прошу помощи.

```
string = input()       
counter = 1
current = 0
following = 1
while True:
    while string[current] == string[following]:
        counter += 1
        if following != len(string)-1:
            current += 1
            following += 1
    print(string[current] + str(counter), end='')
    counter = 1
    if following == len(string)-1:
        break
    current += 1
    following += 1
```

Comment: Под отладчиком запускать не пробовали?

Comment: Ещё Михайло Ломоносов говорил, что если что-то работает не так, то нужно использовать отладчик и ключевое слово print. Зачем тут вообще while True? Делайте просто цикл по строке и все само закончится когда надо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [программа по преобразованию строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/915261/204271)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var string = 'aaaabbcaa';
var result = ''; // expected 'a4b2c1a2'       
var counter = 1;
var current = 0;
var following = 1;
while (true) {
  while (string[current] == string[following]) {
    counter += 1;
    if (following != string.length - 1) {
      current += 1;
      following += 1;
    } else
      break;
  }

  result += string[current] + counter;
  
  if (following == string.length - 1) {
    if (string[current] != string[following])
      result += string[following] + 1;
    break;
  }

  following += 1;
  current += 1;
  counter = 1;
}
console.log(result, "done");
```

Answer (score 0):

Индексный доступ непитоничен. Возможно можно еще лучше оптимизировать, но наивная реализация такая:

```
string = 'aaaabbcaa'
last = ''
result = []
for c in string:
    if c == last:
        counter += 1
    else:
        if last:
            result.append(f'{last}{counter}')
        last = c
        counter = 1
result.append(f'{last}{counter}')
print(''.join(result))
```